# Disable "Starting remoting" output when starting Akka Remoting

Tags: akka, akka-remote-actor

Every time I start Akka Remoting, it logs

```
[INFO] [09/19/2016 09:50:45.952] [main] [akka.remote.Remoting] Starting remoting
[INFO] [09/19/2016 09:50:46.156] [main] [akka.remote.Remoting] Remoting started; listening on addresses :[<adress omitted>]
```

However, I want to disable these messages. I have tried setting `akka.remote.log-remote-lifecycle-events = off`, but this did not disable these particular messages. I would also like to avoid simply setting `akka.loglevel = off`.

I am using versions 2.4.10 of Akka and Akka-remote.

Comment: Why do you want to get rid of those messages?

Comment: Because it makes my log more noisy. I am connecting multiply actor systems that each live in a docker container to form a cluster, so when I do `docker-compose logs`, I see this message from every single container, which makes it somewhat difficult to pick out my own debug outputs.